# SwiftUI ForEach no animation delay

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I recently updated to Xcode 11.3 and now a perviously working animation delay in my `ForEach` statement has failed. Below is a simplified version of my code.

Thanks

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var show: Bool = false

        var transition: AnyTransition {

            let insertion = AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing)

            let removal = AnyTransition.move(edge: .leading)

            return .asymmetric(insertion: insertion, removal: removal)
        }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Button(action: { withAnimation { self.show.toggle() } } ) {
                Text("start animation")
            }
            if show == true {
                test()
                .transition(transition)
            }
        }
    }

}


struct wordArray: Identifiable{

    var id = UUID()
    var words: String

}

struct test: View{

    let circleArray = [

        wordArray(words: "This"),
        wordArray(words: "Should"),
        wordArray(words: "Be"),
        wordArray(words: "Delayed"),

    ]

    var body: some View{

        VStack{

            ForEach(circleArray) { wordArray in
                Text("\(wordArray.words)")
                    .animation(Animation.easeInOut.delay(0.5))
            }

            Text("like")
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut.delay(0.5))

            Text("This")
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut.delay(1))


        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    }
}
```

Comment: As I see more and more areas are reported on SO as broken after update to Xcode 11.3...

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the double VStack. You can change the `VStack` to `Group` in testView.

```
     Group{

        ForEach(circleArray) { wordArray in
            Text("\(wordArray.words)")
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut.delay(0.5))
        }

        Text("like")
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut.delay(0.5))

        Text("This")
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut.delay(1))


    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
```

Comment: This is still not working. I haven't found an answer to fix animation for a group of objects inside a ForEach. Parent transitions just don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problems related to, in many cases, views inside `ForEach` not working with either transitions or animations.

The first solution was to contain the items in a `ForEach` within a `List` view.

The other option is to store the group of views in the `ForEach`, within a `ScrollView`, which is my preferred options, as a list view comes with a great deal of limitations in what and how you can render it.